# Why is stored data corrupted in a generic linked list in C?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I created a generic linked list in C to store data of any type. That involves, of course, using the `void` pointer. I know the code is working generally, but my problem is probably due to memory management surrounding the `void` pointer to store an array of chars (ie C strings). Probably due to my lack of deep understanding of `void` pointers in C?

It is best to show my problem using code examples below for testing purposes.

**slist.h header file**

```
#ifndef _SLIST_H
#define _SLIST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Linked list node data structure for the client program */
typedef struct _listNode {
    void *datum;
    struct _listNode *next;
} listNode, *plistNode;    

/* Generic pointer to data iterators */
typedef void(*listIterator)(void *);

typedef struct {
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned int storageSize;
    listNode *head;
    listNode *tail;
} Slist;

/* Prototype functions */
Slist *createList(const int datasize);
unsigned int destroyList(Slist *pHead);
listNode *insert(Slist *pHead, const void *data);
void iterate(Slist *pHead, listIterator iterator);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**Linked list source code - slist.cpp**

```
#include "slist.h"

Slist *createList(const int datasize) {
    Slist *pHead;

    pHead = (Slist *)malloc(sizeof(Slist));

    if (pHead) {
        pHead->length = 0;
        pHead->storageSize = datasize;
        pHead->head = NULL;
        pHead->tail = NULL;
    }

    return pHead;
}

unsigned int destroyList(Slist *pHead) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    listNode *tnode;
    listNode *cnode = pHead->head;

    while (cnode) {
        count++;

        tnode = cnode;
        cnode = cnode->next;

        free(tnode->datum);
        free(tnode);
    }

    free(pHead);
    pHead = NULL;

    return count;
}

listNode *insert(Slist *pHead, const void *data) {
    listNode *node = (listNode *)malloc(sizeof(listNode));

    if (node) {
        node->datum = malloc(pHead->storageSize);

        if (node->datum) {
            memcpy(node->datum, data, pHead->storageSize);
            node->next = NULL;

            if (pHead->length > 0) {
                pHead->tail->next = node;
                pHead->tail = node;
            } else {
                pHead->head = node;
                pHead->tail = node;
            }

            pHead->length++;
        } else {
            free(node);
            node = NULL;
        }
    }

    return node;
}

void iterate(Slist *pHead, listIterator iterator) {
    listNode *node = pHead->head;

    while (node) {
        iterator(node->datum);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

**Main program**

```
#include "slist.h"

void iterate_string(void *data) {
    printf("Address: %p. Data: %s (Ascii char value)\n", data, *(char**)data);
}

void testStringList() {
    char *buf = NULL;
    Slist *list = createList(sizeof(char *));
    const char *names[] = { "Toyota", "Mercdes", "Jaguar", "Lotus", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen" };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0])); i++) {
        int len = strlen(names[i]) + 1;
        buf = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        strcpy_s(buf, len, names[i]);

        listNode *ptr = insert(list, &buf);

        printf("TEST: Data received after insert -> %s at address %p\n", *(char**)ptr->datum, ptr->datum);

        free(buf);  <-- NOTE: Is that the issue???? Did I misuse it?

        printf("TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> %s at address %p\n\n", *(char**)ptr->datum, ptr->datum);
    }

    iterate(list, iterate_string);

    int killCount = destroyList(list);

    printf("\nList destroyed after killing %d strings...\n", killCount);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testStringList();

    return 0;
}
```

**Generated output 1**

```
TEST: Data received after insert -> Toyota at address 005642F0
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннн at address 005642F0

TEST: Data received after insert -> Mercdes at address 00567A50
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннннu at address 00567A50

TEST: Data received after insert -> Jaguar at address 00567AB8
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннннu at address 00567AB8

TEST: Data received after insert -> Lotus at address 00567B20
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннннu at address 00567B20

TEST: Data received after insert -> Hyundai at address 00567B88
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннннu at address 00567B88

TEST: Data received after insert -> Volkswagen at address 00567BF0
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> ннннннннннннннн at address 00567BF0

Address: 005642F0. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)
Address: 00567A50. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)
Address: 00567AB8. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)
Address: 00567B20. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)
Address: 00567B88. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)
Address: 00567BF0. Data: ннннннннннннннн (Ascii char value)

List destroyed after killing 6 strings...
```

**Generated output 2**

```
TEST: Data received after insert -> Toyota at address 007F3DB0
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Toyota at address 007F3DB0

TEST: Data received after insert -> Mercdes at address 007F3E18
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Mercdes at address 007F3E18

TEST: Data received after insert -> Jaguar at address 007F78D8
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Jaguar at address 007F78D8

TEST: Data received after insert -> Lotus at address 007F7978
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Lotus at address 007F7978

TEST: Data received after insert -> Hyundai at address 007F7A18
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Hyundai at address 007F7A18

TEST: Data received after insert -> Volkswagen at address 007F04D0
TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> Volkswagen at address 007F04D0

Address: 007F3DB0. Data: Toyota (Ascii char value)
Address: 007F3E18. Data: Mercdes (Ascii char value)
Address: 007F78D8. Data: Jaguar (Ascii char value)
Address: 007F7978. Data: Lotus (Ascii char value)
Address: 007F7A18. Data: Hyundai (Ascii char value)
Address: 007F04D0. Data: Volkswagen (Ascii char value)

List destroyed after killing 6 strings...
```

As you can see, I want dynamic storage of strings and store in the generic linked list via void pointer. For the purpose of testing, the `buf` variable is just to copy strings dynamically from the hard-coded array and then stores in the list. Once each data is copied, `buf` is freed and then re-allocated for the next data and so on.

But the result is not what I was hoping for (see Output 1). I have checked the address of the pointer to make sure I was looking at the right spot in memory, but the result was corrupted or lost.

But when I commented out `free(buf)`, then the result was satisfactory (see Output 2), despite the memory leak obviously.

Can someone spot what went wrong with my code and tell me? I am sure I must have overlooked something? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you implement a C style linked list in C++?

Comment: Please don’t tag c *and* c++, they’re different languages. But you’re allocating space for a pointer, then copying a pointer to a local pointer and freeing its contents and wondering why it doesn’t work? You need to copy the *data*, not a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: My real project is C++ in Visual Studio and this code needs to be used in the same project.

Comment: Why do you write a C style list? First approach: use a std::list. Second approach: use STL element like smart pointers. Third approach: use RAII (constructors and destructors). Why do you need C code in C++ files in a C++ project?

Comment: This pretty confusing. Seems you memcpy pointer values and make the nodes point to a pointer that points to a string. If that's what you want, why do you free the string?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, yes, that was my mistake. I thought by copying pointer values would allow the program to retrieve the strings through de-reference, but freeing them was the mistake. Instead, I should have copied the data not saving a pointer to a local variable. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not c++ code, you should use a C compiler, not a c++ compiler.

Your generic list container is designed to handle fixed size objects. In your example these objects are `char *` pointers. You can pass the pointers directly to the `insert` function and the code will work as expected. Here is a modified version of `testStringList`:

```c
void testStringList() {
    Slist *list = createList(sizeof(char *));
    const char *names[] = { "Toyota", "Mercedes", "Jaguar", "Lotus", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen" };
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]); i++) {
        insert(list, &names[i]);
    }

    iterate(list, iterate_string);

    int killCount = destroyList(list);

    printf("\nList destroyed after killing %d strings...\n", killCount);
}
```

This only works if the strings are constant or at least if their lifespan is longer than that of the list and if you can track their allocation separately.

If you want the container to handle variable sized data, where the data size can change for each list node, and make copies of the data, you must change the API and the implementation.

Here is a modified implementation for an appropriate list type:

**vlist.h header file**

```c
#ifndef VLIST_H__
#define VLIST_H__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    /* Linked list node data structure for the client program */
    typedef struct VlistNode {
        void *datum;
        size_t size;
        struct VlistNode *next;
    } VlistNode;

    /* Generic pointer to vdata iterators */
    typedef void (*VlistIterator)(void *datum, size_t size);

    typedef struct {
        size_t length;
        VlistNode *head;
        VlistNode *tail;
    } Vlist;

    /* Prototype functions */
    Vlist *Vlist_create(void);
    size_t Vlist_destroy(Vlist *pHead);
    VlistNode *Vlist_insert(Vlist *pHead, const void *data, size_t size);
    void Vlist_iterate(Vlist *pHead, VlistIterator iterator);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // VLIST_H__
```

**Linked list source code - Vlist.c**

```c
#include "Vlist.h"

Vlist *Vlist_create(void) {
    Vlist *pHead = (Vlist *)malloc(sizeof(Vlist));

    if (pHead) {
        pHead->length = 0;
        pHead->head = NULL;
        pHead->tail = NULL;
    }
    return pHead;
}

size_t Vlist_destroy(Vlist *pHead) {
    size_t count = 0;
    VlistNode *cnode = pHead->head;

    while (cnode) {
        VlistNode *tnode = cnode;

        cnode = cnode->next;

        free(tnode->datum);
        free(tnode);
        count++;
    }
    free(pHead);
    return count;
}

VlistNode *Vlist_insert(Vlist *pHead, const void *data, size_t size) {
    VlistNode *node = (VlistNode *)malloc(sizeof(VlistNode));

    if (node) {
        node->datum = malloc(size);
        if (node->datum) {
            memcpy(node->datum, data, size);
            node->size = size;
            node->next = NULL;

            if (pHead->length > 0) {
                pHead->tail->next = node;
                pHead->tail = node;
            } else {
                pHead->head = node;
                pHead->tail = node;
            }
            pHead->length++;
        } else {
            free(node);
            node = NULL;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

void Vlist_iterate(Vlist *pHead, VlistIterator iterator) {
    VlistNode *node = pHead->head;

    while (node) {
        iterator(node->datum, node->size);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

**Main program**

```c
#include "Vlist.h"

void iterate_string(void *data, size_t size) {
    printf("Address: %p, Size: %u, Data: %s (Ascii string)\n", data, (unsigned)size, data);
}

void testStringList() {
    Vlist *list = Vlist_create();
    const char *names[] = { "Toyota", "Mercedes", "Jaguar", "Lotus", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen" };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0])); i++) {
        Vlist_insert(list, names[i], strlen(names[i]) + 1);
    }

    Vlist_iterate(list, iterate_string);

    int killCount = Vlist_destroy(list);

    printf("\nList destroyed after killing %d strings...\n", killCount);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testStringList();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address: 0x7fe59d4026c0, Size: 7, Data: Toyota (Ascii string)
Address: 0x7fe59d4026f0, Size: 9, Data: Mercedes (Ascii string)
Address: 0x7fe59d402720, Size: 7, Data: Jaguar (Ascii string)
Address: 0x7fe59d402750, Size: 6, Data: Lotus (Ascii string)
Address: 0x7fe59d402780, Size: 8, Data: Hyundai (Ascii string)
Address: 0x7fe59d4027b0, Size: 11, Data: Volkswagen (Ascii string)

List destroyed after killing 6 strings...
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I misunderstood the difference between storing pointer values and  saving real data values. I will change everything to pure C code only as that is what I really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In main you do:

```
listNode* ptr = insert(list, &buf);
```

You want that to be:

```
listNode* ptr = insert(list, buf);
```

because you want to store the data `buf` points to, not `buf` itself, which will change with every iteration or call.

And indeed, you don;t want to `free(buf)` because the memory is in use (you just stored it in the list).

Comment: They also need to handle data size etc etc. This isn’t enough to fix the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, that is handled: `Slist *list = createList(sizeof(char*));` But he freed `buf`, which he shouldn't (added that to my solution).

Comment: They also have to not use double pointers, not copy anything, not allocate more memory... It’s full of issues.

Answer (score -1):

Writting C code in a C++ project makes this code much more complex than it actually should be. You can solve the problems using C++ elements. This is an equivalent C++ code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <string>

void iterate_string(const char *data)
{
    std::printf("Address: %p. Data: %s (Ascii char value)\n", data, data);
}

void testStringList() {
    std::list<std::string> list;
    const std::array<std::string, 6> names = { "Toyota", "Mercdes", "Jaguar", "Lotus", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen" };
    
    for (const auto &name : names) {
        list.push_back(name);

        std::printf("TEST: Data received after insert -> %s at address %p\n", list.back().c_str(), list.back().c_str());

        // std::printf("TEST: Data after releasing temp buffer -> %s at address %p\n\n", list.back().c_str(), list.back().c_str());
    }

    for (const auto &name : list) {
        iterate_string(name.c_str());
    }

    std::printf("\nList destroyed after killing %zu strings...\n", list.size());
}

int main()
{
    testStringList();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see you don't have to handle memory leaks. STL containers will do this for you.